# Override Unity bulk registration to assign different lifetimemanager

Tags: c#, unity-container

I am using version 3.5.1404.0 of Unity and in my registrations I have first a Bulk registration defaulting to Hierarchical

```
container.RegisterTypes(
  AllClasses.FromAssemblies(false,
       new[]
       {
           Assembly.GetAssembly(typeof (IMyService<>))
       })
     , WithMappings.FromMatchingInterface,
     WithName.Default,
     WithLifetime.Hierarchical);
```

followed by an single mapping registration to override the lifetime manager (Hiararchical) assigned to my service.

```
container.RegisterType<IMyService<SomeEntity>, MyCustomService<SomeEntity>>(new TransientLifetimeManager());
```

But when I examine the registration in my unit-tests then the LifetimeManager is Hierarchical.

```
// this assertion fails
registration.LifetimeManagerType.Should().Be(typeof(TransientLifetimeManager));
```

Is there any way to force the use of TransientLifetimeManager?

Comment: Try to use `RegisterInstance` (instead of `RegisterType`) it should override registration.

Comment: I am unable to reproduce your issue. When I try it, the lifetime manager is `TransientLifetimeManager`. Are you sure that you are checking against the correct registration item?

Comment: RegisterInstance uses a different LifetimeManager (ContainerController). So I can't use that.

Comment: @YacoubMassad i ve been investigating more on it thanks to fact that you couldnt reproduce, and finally found that the bulk registration is registering the MyCustomService with Hierarchial lifetime manager without a mapping to the interface, because WithMappings.FromMatchingInterface couldnt create one based on convention.

Comment: @IbrahimbenSalah, I am still not able to reproduce. Try to reproduce in your environment with only this code

Comment: @YacoubMassad The reason of this weird behaviour is the generic declararion, so I updated the example code accordingly. The problem is that MyCustomService<> is registered with Hierarchical while I only register MyCustomService<SomeEntity> to be Transient. So Unity chooses to ignore this override because of some clear and undisputed reason I don't know about :(.

Answer (score 0):

UnityContainer setup code should also include

```
container.RegisterType<MyCustomService<>>(new TransientLifetimeManager());
```